# how to add limit records in wordpress query

Tags: wp-query, database

I have this query which is returning the all records from database whose type is equal to  'quote2'. No I want to know how to limit the record. I mean I just want to show last 10 records added in the database. I am new in wordpress and want to learn syntax of my required query.

```
global $wpdb;
 $querystr = "select $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'quote2'
";
```

Comment: If your query is so simple, I wouldn't suggest using any SQL. Instead refer to WP Query Class " http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query ". It is the best and more efficient way of querying the database.

Comment: Also this question seems more like due to the lack of "SQL" knowledge. So i would suggest you to refer to some sql resources that are available online for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do, can be achieved by means of the `WP_Query` class.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'quote2',
    'posts_per_page' => 10, // or something else
));
```

Now you can work with `$query` like:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post;
        ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); </h1>
        <?php the_content();
        <?php
    }
else {
    // No posts...
}
```

If you just want to get access to the posts, you can do so via `$query->posts`.